# What happens when T and S are not unitarily equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ such that the $\dim V=4$, the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is the same of $S$. The question is, what happens when T and S are not unitarily equivalent given this conditions?

The answer of this question is that the minimal polynomial of this operators has a form of the square of a polynomial of degree $1$, $(q^2)$. But I couldn't see why. Could someone help? I was trying to use rational form in some way but I got nothing.

Comment: Does $F$ have characteristic $0$?

Comment: It doesn't have to be. F is an arbitrary field